# regex fun - finding some but skipping others

Tags: javascript, regex

Having some real trouble with regex. Shocker.

**Goal:** Match {{ through }} if and only if there is a [[ and/or ]] present inside.

Given the sample below, I would want to **match everything but** the {{three}} (and One, two, four, six, eight, thirteen and sixteen)

My english translation of my current regex is: "Give me everything between left braces that are followed by a space or word that are followed by two left brackets".

I think I've gone a little overboard with the look-aheads.

```
"One two {{three}} four {{ [[five]]}} six {{[[seven]]}} eight {{ Nine: [[ten]] }} {{Eleven: [[twelve]]}} thirteen {{Fourteen: [[fifteen]] }} sixteen"
.match(/\{{2}(?=(\s|\w(?=\[{2}))).{7}/g);
```

The .{7} is so I can simply see what my results are in the console.

**Result I'm hunting is:**

```
["{{ [[five]]}}", "{{[[seven]]}}", "{{ Nine: [[ten]] }}", "{{Eleven: [[twelve]]}}", "{{Fourteen: [[fifteen]] }}"]
```

Please help a dude.

Thanks!

Comment: `only if there is a [[ and/or ]] present inside.` Inside ? There is no concept of _inside_ in regular expressions unless you're using an engine that can do balanced text. Certainly not JS..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex you need is this:

```
/\{\{(?=(?:(?!\}\}).)*(?:\[\[|\]\])).*?\}\}/g
```

Example code:

```
var str ="One two {{three}} four {{ [[five]]}} six {{[[seven]]}} eight {{ Nine: [[ten]] }} {{Eleven: [[twelve]]}} thirteen {{Fourteen: [[fifteen]] }} sixteen",
    regex = /\{\{(?=(?:(?!\}\}).)*(?:\[\[|\]\])).*?\}\}/g;
str.match(regex); // result: ["{{ [[five]]}}", "{{[[seven]]}}", "{{ Nine: [[ten]] }}", "{{Eleven: [[twelve]]}}", "{{Fourteen: [[fifteen]] }}"]
```

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/xL7kW6/2)

This works in the following way:

- `/` start of the regex
- `\{\{` matches `{{`
- `(?=` lookahead start

  - `(?:` non-matching group start

    - `(?!\}\})` don't match `}}`
    - `.` any character
  - `)` non-matching group end
  - `*` repeat that non-matching group zero or more times
  - `(?:` non-matching group start

    - `\[\[|\]\]` either `[[` or `]]`
  - `)` non-matching group end
- `)` lookahead end
- `.*?` zero or more characters, non-greedy
- `\}\}` matches `}}`
- `/` end of the regex
- `g` global match flag

In other words, it looks for `{{` followed by zero or more characters that aren't `}}`, then `[[` or `]]`, then zero or more characters, then `}}`.